# Importing files into R if filename matches specified criteria

Tags: r, string, csv, import

Using R I am trying to loop the import of csv files iff the filename contains a specific string

For example, I have a list of files with names 'file01042016_abc.csv', 'file020142016_abc.csv', 'file03042016_abc.csv'...'file26092019_abc.csv' and I have a list of specific values in the format '01042016', '05042016', '09042016', etc.

I would like to only import the files if the filename contains the string value in the second list.

I can import them altogether (shown below) but there are several thousand files and takes a considerable amount of time so would like to reduce it by importing only the files needed based on condition mentioned above.

```
files <- list.files(path)

for (i in 1:length(files)) {

  assign(paste("Df", files[i], sep = "_"), read.csv(paste(path, files[i], sep='')))

}
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just prefilter the `files` vector, and then loop as normal.

```
files0 <- c('file01042016_abc.csv', 'file020142016_abc.csv', 
            'file03042016_abc.csv', 'file26092019_abc.csv', 
            'file09042016_abc.csv')

k <- c('01042016', '05042016', '09042016')
pat <- paste(k, collapse="|")

files <- grep(pat, files0, value=TRUE)
files
# [1] "file01042016_abc.csv" "file09042016_abc.csv"
```

Comment: Nice answer.  It looks like mine ^ ^

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yeah, we both had the same basic idea using `grep()` to select the relevant file names, but as long as a function is vectorized I prefer to keep it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex along with `grepl`:

```
files <- list.files(path)
formats <- c("01042016", "05042016", "09042016")
regex <- paste(formats, collapse="|")

sapply(files, function(x) {
    if (grepl(regex, x)) {
        assign(paste("Df", x, sep = "_"), read.csv(paste(path, x, sep='')))
    }
})
```

The strategy here is to generate a single regex alternation containing all numeric filename fragments which would whitelist a file as a candidate to be read.  For the sample data given above, `regex` would become:

```
01042016|05042016|09042016
```

Then, we call `grepl` on each file to see if it matches one of the whitelisted patterns.  Note that I switched to using `sapply` as `files.list` returns a character vector of filenames.